# How to make Emacs run from a single Gnome desktop icon?

Tags: server

I often use Emacs with Linux Manjaro and Gnome.  I need straightforward access to Emacs from desktop.  Therefore, I have pinned the Emacs icon to dash so I can launch Emacs by clicking the Emacs icon.

However, the Emacs icon does not activate (has no dot below) while an activated Emacsclient icon pops up in the dash.

[image: screen copy]

I don't like this.  How to make Emacs run from a single icon just like any desktop application?

Emacs does run:

```
alba@mac2011-manjaro% ps -u alba|tail -5
  19713 ?        00:00:00 python3
  19754 ?        00:00:00 obexd
  20336 ?        00:00:01 emacs
  20377 pts/1    00:00:00 ps
  20378 pts/1    00:00:00 tail
```

Emacsclient does not run:

```
alba@mac2011-manjaro% ps -u alba|grep client
```

(empty output)

Files corresponding to the desktop icons:

```
alba@mac2011-manjaro% cat /usr/share/applications/emacs.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Emacs
GenericName=Text Editor
Comment=Edit text
MimeType=text/english;text/plain;text/x-makefile;text/x-c++hdr;text/x-c++src;text/x-chdr;text/x-csrc;text/x-java;text/x-moc;text/x-pascal;text/x-tcl;text/x-tex;application/x-shellscript;text/x-c;text/x-c++;
Exec=emacs %F
Icon=emacs
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;TextEditor;
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass=Emacs
alba@mac2011-manjaro% cat /usr/share/applications/emacsclient.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Emacs (Client)
GenericName=Text Editor
Comment=Edit text
MimeType=text/english;text/plain;text/x-makefile;text/x-c++hdr;text/x-c++src;text/x-chdr;text/x-csrc;text/x-java;text/x-moc;text/x-pascal;text/x-tcl;text/x-tex;application/x-shellscript;text/x-c;text/x-c++;
Exec=sh -c "if [ -n \\"\\$*\\" ]; then exec emacsclient --alternate-editor= --display=\\"\\$DISPLAY\\" \\"\\$@\\"; else exec emacsclient --alternate-editor= --create-frame; fi" placeholder %F
Icon=emacs
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;TextEditor;
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass=Emacs
Keywords=emacsclient;
Actions=new-window;new-instance;

[Desktop Action new-window]
Name=New Window
Exec=/usr/bin/emacsclient --alternate-editor= --create-frame %F

[Desktop Action new-instance]
Name=New Instance
Exec=emacs %F
```

Comment: Did you compile your own emacs or was it installed via your distros packages?

Comment: I don't use `emacsclient`, but in some Linux flavors it is possible to create a custom desktop launcher file with either a command line, or a path to a script.   For example, in Debian or Ubuntu, the file would be created at `/usr/share/applications/my_custom_emacs_launcher.desktop`.  If there is a command-line that works for you, then perhaps you could create a custom launcher that does what you want.  The `Exec` portion of the desktop file is what controls the custom command line or path to a script containing whatever is desired.  And, of course, you can set  the path to the desired icon.

Comment: (1) Please remove the last paragraph. One problem per post, please. (2) Please make the title more specific: *"Just like any desktop application"* is unclear and too general. Thx.

Comment: This Emacs is a Manjaro package.  I have tried also Emacs from Flatpak, it does not have this problem but has other problems.

Comment: Yes, one problem per post.  So I have removed the other problem.   Let me keep as comment that I tried to use only  the emacsclient icon.  It almosts works, except that emacsclient does not load my init file.

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution based on comments.  Since for some unclear reason starting Emacs activates the Emacsclient icon, an idea was to use directly the Emacsclient icon, with the difficulty that [Emacsclient does not load the init file](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/60071/emacsclient-not-loading-init-file-changes).

Emacsclient can be forced to load the init file by preventing it from connecting to any existing Emacs process that can be used as server.

Kill all Emacs processes:

```
alba@mac2011-manjaro% ps -u alba|grep emacs
   3121 ?        00:00:01 emacs
alba@mac2011-manjaro% kill -9 3121
```

If Emacs runs as a systemd service, systemd will create a new Emacs automatically.  (Check if the Emacs service is on with `systemctl --user status emacs.service`.)

Stop the Emacs service:

```
alba@mac2011-manjaro% systemctl --user stop emacs.service
```

(This choice can be made persistent across session with `systemctl --user disable emacs.service`.)

A command that *works* (starts Emacsclient and loads the init file) is `emacsclient --alternate-editor=emacs --create-frame`: as Emacsclient does not find a server (for all the previous killing), it calls `emacs`, which loads the init file.

Copy `/usr/share/applications/emacsclient.desktop` to `~/.local/share/aplications` and add `emacs` after each occurence of `--alternate-editor=`.

(To check that the newly created `~/.local/share/aplications/emacsclient.desktop` is effective, change the icon name to some absurd value like `Icon=emacssss` and, after a dew seconds, no need to relog, the Emacsclient gnu icon is replaced by a generic icon.)

Use Emacsclient instead of Emacs.

Answer (score 0):

Just like this:

```
sudo rm /usr/share/applications/emacsclient.desktop
```

(Tested today with Emacs from the [Ubuntuhandbook PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntuhandbook1/+archive/ubuntu/ppa), Ubuntu 22.04.)